Question closed, then deleted after I edited it for review
Link to question. Closed for asking multiple questions in one. I changed that, banner at the top said question's in review but nothing happened until it was autodeleted.
I'd like feedback on what to do next. Is there any particular reason remaining for keeping it deleted/closed?

It was deleted by the Roomba. Voting to undelete is the only option barring mod action.

Are you asking why it was closed/about getting it opened, are you asking about the deletion or is your question about something else?

@dan1st "Is there any particular reason remaining for keeping it deleted/closed?"

Debugging questions generally require a minimal reproducible example so I guess that would be a reason for it to remain closed - unless you can provide us with a reproducer. People on Stack Overflow can't solve your problem if they can't reproduce it. Since you also added suppressing possibly being an option, I could also see an argument for reopening if you make it clear what you want to be supressed and what shouldn't be supressed.

@dan1st It's not a "debug my code" question, it's a "how to get rid of these reported leaks?" question. From my attempts (and failures) to make a MRE, I don't think it's tied to a particular code. If I eventually find a MRE, I'll add it with big warnings not to overfocus on it. Regarding the 2nd part, I extra specified that I only need to deal with: "memory leaks which only contain address sanitizer library and <unknown module>". How about that?

"Is there any particular reason remaining for keeping it deleted/closed?" - The "needs more focus" close reason is not just about asking multiple questions in one. Please read the guidance in the FAQ on Meta, and make sure you understand that we don't do debugging for you.

"If I eventually find a MRE, I'll add it with big warnings not to overfocus on it." Sorry, that's not how the site works. If your question is about why something happens, we are only concerned with your MRE, and not the original context. The purpose of the site is to answer questions, not to help people fix the original code that motivated those questions.

@KarlKnechtel And I don't want help with fixing the original code, the question I asked isn't about fixing the original code, and I explicitly said here that I'm not asking for debugging the original code. I'll repeat it again, just for you: I'm NOT asking for debugging. I'm doing the debugging myself. Stop saying otherwise. Is your answer that my question absolutely needs MRE code?

As to "we are only concerned with your MRE, and not the original context" - it's "I am", not "we are". I've seen comments asking for context.

And I've read the FAQ link before and I can't see why it'd be too big for only one question after edit. The only part of FAQ that I could see fitting the given close reason was multiple questions in one. Lack of MRE isn't under "needs more focus", but under "needs debugging details".

it's a "how to get rid of these reported leaks?" question. - On Stack Overflow, that's pretty much considered to be a debugging question needing a MRE. You have some leaks/issues in your code and want to fix it. If people cannot reproduce these, they cannot really help you.

Let's go back to what I originally asked for: current reasons for keeping it closed. If it's "this needs a MRE to demonstrate the issue in general and provide a starting point for debugging because it's unanswerably difficult otherwise", that's perfectly fine, I accept that. If it's "you're asking us to debug your specific code, post MRE of that", that's false and I have to keep pointing out since I believe that notion only prevents my question from being answered, going against SO's purpose as a site to answer questions.

Note again I've been working on MRE. I'll post it when done, possibly as a separate question depending on how different it turns out to be.

I believe that the Roomba deleting questions with pending reopen tasks is rude and should be changed.

If it's "you're asking us to debug your specific code, post MRE of that", that's false and I have to keep pointing out since I believe that notion only prevents my question from being answered, going against SO's purpose as a site to answer questions - What about that would be "false" if the SO guidelines/standards require a MRE for debugging questions? (1/2)

If you meant that your question wouldn't be directly about fixing these issues in your specific code but suppressing/getting rid of a specific issue, I would (personally) consider that as needing a MRE. If you want to just suppress all warnings about leaks in <unknown module>, I'd say that's fine (it has also been reopened by now) but I would prefer it being very clear about that/what exactly you are asking (I didn't necessarily interpret it that way in the revision of when you posted the question). (2/2)

It's been autodeleted again. Sigh.

Because there was no activity on the question itself, @Xellos , so it still fitted the requirements for auto deletion after it was undeleted (comments don't count). There's some changes you've been asked to make to said question; if you had made those with an edit it wouldn't have been deleted. You might be better off asking a new, better, question (don't just copy pasta your old question, write a new one from scratch).
